# Wait for file to exist in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page, where the user is able to trigger a console app on our server, which generates a file. What I want is the user to see a message that states 'Requesting file', then as soon as the file becomes available (i.e. `File.Exists` for the file returns true), the Requesting file message will change to a link of the file.

Is this easy to accomplish in ASP.NET?

Comment: Easy depends on your competence in all three areas. You'll need to make a javascript ajax call to a webmethod in your backend which starts the console app and waits for it to finish and then return a status back to the javascript ajax call's callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you web page implement a JSON call to a certain WebMethod which checks if the file has be been generated or not.

you can add your message in the calling function and clear it in the complete event, where you can create the link to the file also

```
function ddlLeaveChanged(sender, e) {


if (leaveTypeId != '-1' && dateFrom != '' && leaveStatusId != '-1') {
     $('#lblMessage').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: WebServiceUrl + 'YourMethod',

        success: FunctionSuccedded,
        error: FunctionFailed
    });
}

function FunctionsSuccedded(result, e) {
if (result) { $('#lblMessage').hide(); }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using a combination of:

- [Javascript `setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)
- `[jquery.Ajax][2]`
- [ASP.NET Web Method](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

A javascript function can be triggered every `x` seconds (using `setInterval`) to trigger a Web Method using AJAX to check whether the file exists.

Check the links I've provided above. These should be all you need to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid file systems all together you could key off a database field as well, i.e. when the linked is clicked an entry is made into a database table of some sort that signifies file creation pending, and then periodically check if the status has been updated. The server side code would update that same key and have a url in the datastore as well, so you could just check for the status of file created and the link the datastore. This would also result in you having a history of file creation, which you could purge as you saw fit, so from an ASP.NET perspective you would only be relying on data access code to determine if your file was created.

Answer (score 0):

Not much different in ASP.NET vs any other platform. You can go about it like this:

1. Make AJAX call when the triggering link is clicked.
2. Server-side code that handles the call launches an external process to generate the file, and waits for it to complete.
3. After checking that the file is indeed there, reply to the AJAX call with a meaningful message (i.e. one that contains enough information to build a link to the file).